# Написать запрос, который выберет название мероприятия по которому больше всего заказов

Tags: sql, база-данных

> Напишите запрос, который выберет название мероприятия
>   (events.caption), по которому больше трех заявок.
>
> Есть две таблицы
>
> первая таблица events
>
> - id    captoin
> - 1         first
> - 2         second
> - 3         thirdth
>
>   вторая таблица bids
> - id       id_event        name
> - 1             1                aa
> - 2             2                bb
> - 3             2                cc
> - 4             2                dd
> - 5             2                ee
> - 6             1                ff

```
SELECT id_event, COUNT(id_event) AS cnt
FROM bids
GROUP BY id_event HAVING cnt NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 3;
```

Вот этот запрос выводить  id_event(2) и количество cnt4

- id_event            cnt
- 2                       4

---

То есть осталось лишь сравнить переменные id( из таблицы events )и id_event(из таблицы bids) чтобы на выходе было название мероприятия.

Comment: По какому полю вы связывание таблицы?

Comment: id и id_event, то есть если id_event=1 то id=1  выводится названия первого мероприятия

Comment: Группируем, считаем заказы, сортируем по убыванию количества, берём первый

Comment: я написал запрос который выводит id_event и количество cnt  SELECT id_event, COUNT(id_event) AS cnt FROM  bids GROUP BY id_event HAVING cnt NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 3;      но осталось лишь сравнить id ( таблицы events ) c (из таблицы bids) чтобы на выходе было название мероприятия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте join, чтобы получить название мероприятия.

```
SELECT caption, COUNT(b.id_event) AS cnt
FROM bids b
join events e on b.id_event=e.id
GROUP BY e.caption
HAVING cnt>3;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает.